# QLPreviewController ios6 get as UIImage

Tags: ios6, qlpreviewcontroller

Is there any way to get a UIImage representation of the QLPreviewController's view in ios6?

Answer (score 0):

yes You can

**[QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewControllerDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009665) can display previews for the following items**:

1. iWork documents
2. Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
3. Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
4. PDF files
5. Images
6. Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)
7. Comma-separated value (csv) files

For More about QLPreviewController Refer this [Link](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2012/07/tutorial-how-to-use-qlpreviewcontroller.html) & for Documentation Refer this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewControllerDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009665)

Comment: I see that `[self presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];` creates the QLPreviewController that allows it to view the types of documents you listed. After the QLPreviewController is created, is there a way to programmatically get a UIImage (scrape) of the QLPreviewController's view (whatever document is being shared)